# How to include bower component in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, bower

I'm starting with bower and  followed [this tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-bower) at first. I have no problems with installing a package, but with how to use it in a static web page.

I could obviously do something like:

```
<script src="bower_components/module_name/module.js"></script>
```

for each the components I need, but it seems to me not the good way to do. So I think I am missing something which could link the page generation to my bower components.

May be there a bower component which could help me to include all packages in a `bower_components` directory.

Comment: "in a static web page" mean without web server?

Comment: that means a static html file served or not by a web server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is one way to do it but I usually use bower in conjunction with other build tools, like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). Then you can use a task, like [grunt-bower-task](https://github.com/yatskevich/grunt-bower-task), to copy only the necessary files to a directory of your choosing.

If you are feeling really ambitious, you could leverage the [bower api](http://bower.io/docs/api/) to roll your own build solution that extracts the "main" files into your project.

Another thing to be aware of, is that not every dependency you will want to include will implement bower's configuration properly (example: missing `main` attribute or `bower.json` file). There will also be those projects that require you to include assets (fonts, images, etc.), which bower doesn't currently solve for. In these cases, you will need to come up with a way to move the files around. I always end up having to use something like [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) to get everything in it's place.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, bower is "just" a plugin registry like npm for node modules?

Comment: @Gael, that is correct. Only, bower is used to manage your frontend dependencies.